# How to create multiple rows from a single row - normalize a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am pretty new to SQL and trying to figure this out:

I have a table called BUDGET that has 12 columns for each month of the year, displaying the budget balance of that month. So the table looks like this:

```
[Department]  [Year]  [Month1] [Month2] .... [Month12]  
ABCD           2010   $5000     $5500   .....  $4000
ABCD           2011   $6000     $6500   .....  $3000
```

What I am trying to do is to normalize this table and break each row into 12 rows, each row with a date field in the following format. I also want to have a [Balance] column that displays the value of that month. So, the normalized table will look like this:

```
[Department]  [Date]     [Balance] 
ABCD          20100101     $5000   
ABCD          20100201     $5500 
ABCD          20100301     .....
ABCD          .......      ......
```

I tried using CROSS JOIN on the same table but failed. I also tried using a while loop but that failed as well. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: if you are on SQL Server 2005 or higher, take a look at the PIVOT and UNPIVOT operators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just for fun here's a CROSS APPLY solution:

```
SELECT
   B.Department,
   DateAdd(month, (B.Year - 1900) * 12 + M.Mo - 1, 0) [Date],
   M.Balance
FROM
   dbo.Budget B
   CROSS APPLY (
      VALUES
      (1, Month1), (2, Month2), (3, Month3), (4, Month4), (5, Month5), (6, Month6),
      (7, Month7), (8, Month8), (9, Month9), (10, Month10), (11, Month11), (12, Month12)
   ) M (Mo, Balance);
```

It's really no different than @Aaron Bertrand's UNPIVOT, without using UNPIVOT.

If you must have the date as a string, then put strings in the CROSS APPLY like `('01', Month1)` and change the SELECT to `Convert(char(4), B.Year) + M.Mo`.

Comment: I think this might make another good blog post. I bet many readers would find some of these techniques new, and most would be surprised which solution on this page performs best.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Put that on the blogoverflow!

Comment: @JNK I think you know I have a different blogging priority now. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Please tag me on chat when you write it! The CROSS APPLY method and CROSS JOIN methods have one less operator in the query plan, iirc. Also, you might like to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737314/logging-update-operation-in-triggers/11789911#11789911) for a two-column UNPIVOT using CROSS APPLY to show why CROSS APPLY is so stinking wonderful.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great.. Great learning experience for me.

Comment: @ChangeTheWorld: I would be interested in the performance of the various solutions here with your actual data. Could I interest you in posting an answer with the output of [`SET STATISTICS TIME ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx) for the various queries?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Have you blogged about this yet?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I enjoyed meeting you at PASS. Blogged yet? :)

Comment: @ErikE no sir, been a little busy. :-) Cheers

Comment: Cross apply is my favorite discovery this year. It's like the swiss army knife of TSQL

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
  Department, 
  [Date] = DATEADD(MONTH, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([Month],6,2))-1, 
     DATEADD(YEAR, [Year]-1900, 0)), 
  Balance
FROM
  dbo.BUDGET AS b
  UNPIVOT 
  (
    Balance FOR [Month] IN 
    (
      Month1, Month2,  Month3,  Month4,
      Month5, Month6,  Month7,  Month8,
      Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12
    )
  ) AS y
ORDER BY Department, [Date];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. No need to get all fancy about it.

```
select department = b.department ,
       year       = b.year       ,
       month      = m.month      ,
       balance    = case m.month
                    when  1 then b.Month1
                    when  2 then b.Month2
                    when  3 then b.Month3
                    when  4 then b.Month4
                    when  5 then b.Month5
                    when  6 then b.Month6
                    when  7 then b.Month7
                    when  8 then b.Month8
                    when  9 then b.Month9
                    when 10 then b.Month10
                    when 11 then b.Month11
                    when 12 then b.Month12
                    else         null
                    end
from dbo.budget b
join (           select month =  1
       union all select month =  2
       union all select month =  3
       union all select month =  4
       union all select month =  5
       union all select month =  6
       union all select month =  7
       union all select month =  8
       union all select month =  9
       union all select month = 10
       union all select month = 11
       union all select month = 12
     ) m on 1 = 1  -- a dummy join: we want the cartesian product here so as to expand every row in budget into twelve, one per month of the year.
```

Comment: I don't think it's about "fancy" it's about minimizing code. This is more efficient but it ain't pretty. :-) Also you have some syntax errors - what are `d.` and `t.`? The join involves aliases `b` and `m` only.

Comment: When a cross join is required, why not use `CROSS JOIN` instead of a dummy condition?