# TSQL-View: How to multiplicate the rows of a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, view

I have a table with two columns and for example three rows as shown above. Then I want to create a view on this table.

This view should show for each line in the table as many lines as there is written in this line.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, has someone an example how to build a view with TSQL?

Example:

[image]

Comment: In SQL, in general, you should be thinking in terms of sets. what you've shown on the right isn't a set, because sets don't contain duplicates. Why are you trying to do this in SQL?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: `SQL` works on multisets, not sets, that's why it has `DISTINCT`, `UNION ALL` etc. "Sets" is just easier to utter when you want to dissuade someone from using cursors.

Comment: @Quassnoi - I know it can produce results which aren't sets. But IMO, you should always ask yourself *why* you're producing something that isn't set-like. It's also why I included "in general".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: to show results to a person, for instance, and for million other reasons.

Comment: I have found something similar to my problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837928/how-to-create-multiple-rows-from-a-single-row-normalize-a-table

But what should I do? UNION or CROSS JOIN, or CROSS APPLY or how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should join this table with some table which has field with 1,2,3,4,5,6,.... numbers. 
For example:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/baf46/14)

```
with t0 as 
( select 1 n
  union all
  select 2 n
  union all 
  select 3 n 
 ),
tCount as
(select ROW_number() over (order by t1.n) rn
from t0,
     t0 as t1,
     t0 as t2,
     t0 as t3,
     t0 as t4
)
select t.* from t
join tCount on t.Number>=tCount.rn
order by name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive CTE to split the values, similar to this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT name, value
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name, value-1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE value-1 >= 1
)
SELECT t.name, t.value
FROM yourtable t
inner join CTE c
  on t.name = c.name
ORDER BY name, value
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/627db/1)

The result is:

```
|  NAME | VALUE |
-----------------
|  milk |     4 |
|  milk |     4 |
|  milk |     4 |
|  milk |     4 |
| sugar |     2 |
| sugar |     2 |
|   tea |     7 |
|   tea |     7 |
|   tea |     7 |
|   tea |     7 |
|   tea |     7 |
|   tea |     7 |
|   tea |     7 |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH    q(n) AS
        (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  n + 1
        FROM    q
        WHERE   n <
                (
                SELECT  MAX(repeats)
                FROM    mytable
                )
        )
SELECT  t.*
FROM    mytable t
JOIN    q
ON      q.n <= t.repeats
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
;WITH T AS(
    SELECT 
        COl1, Col2, 1 AS NUM 
    FROM TableName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        T1.COl1, T1.Col2, T.NUM+1 AS NUM 
    FROM TableName T1 INNER JOIN T ON T1.Col1=T.Col1
    WHERE T.NUM+1<=T1.Col2
)
SELECT COl1, Col2 FROM T ORDER BY COl1
```